# How to use Django login functionality using already created MySQL database table?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have Database **Student**, in that database I have one table **Student_login**
whose structure is :
         **Student_id** ---**Integer**

**Student_Username**-----**Varchar(PlainText)**

**Student_password**-----**Varchar(PlainText)**

Now I have to use already present database for **Django Login Functionality**

Django creates its own table for login instead of it I want to use **Student_login** table for login and also Django encrypts password but I don't want to encrypt the password because some other people are also using same table.

How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A special place in hell is reserved for people who create plain text password fields in 2019. Implement a migration scheme for 'other people' to validate against an encrypted/hashed password.

Comment: @Aayan migrate your user passwords and store hashed ones and configure Django to use that Hasher, generate migrations and apply those migrations using `--fake-initial` and generate a model for the user and specify the existing table in `Meta`, you should get a high-level idea about how to achieve this.